# Minimize the sum of gaps

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard

I have a set of $n$ objects $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ where object $i$ has weight $w(i)$ and we have a capacity $W$. I would like to pick a subset $S=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of the objects in order to minimize $$\sum_{j=0}^m(a_{j+1}-a_{j}-1),$$ (assuming that $a_0=0$ and $a_{m+1}=n+1$) while respecting the capacity, i.e., $$\sum_{j=1}^mw(a_j)\leq W.$$

The objective is like the sum of gaps between chosen objects.

Is this problem NP-hard or can we find a polynomial time algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $k$ and $\sigma$, let $A(k,\sigma)$ be the minimum of $\sum_{j=1}^m w(a_j)$ over all subsets $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ containing $k$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^m (a_{j+1} - a_j - 1) = \sigma$; note that there are $O(n)$ choices for each of $k$ and $\sigma$. You can compute $A(k,\sigma)$ for all $k,\sigma$ using dynamic programming, and use it to solve your problem in polytime.

Comment: Thanks. Calculating the minimum overall subsets, isn't it exponential? For $k=n$, it is $O(2^n)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: Not really. I know some basics. Do you mean dynamic programming will find the minimum without looking at all subsets?

Comment: Dynamic programming can solve it in polynomial time. After you familiarize yourself with the technique, you should be able to use my outline to come up with such an algorithm. Unfortunately I cannot help any further. Dynamic programming is a standard technique, and there are many places where you can read about it.